# Handling Text efficiently with multiple threads in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am working on an app where I am displaying some logs from different tasks running within the app that I would like the user to know about (~3k lines of logs or more per session), currently I am using a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`

The view code-behind:

```
    private void OnConsoleLoggerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var args = (ConsoleEventArgs) e;

        switch (args.EventType)
        {
            case ConsoleLoggerEventType.Log:
                ConsoleFlowDocument.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    var log = new Paragraph(new Run(args.Message)) { FontSize = 12 };
                    ConsoleFlowDocument.Document.Blocks.Add(log);
                });
                break;
            
            case ConsoleLoggerEventType.Error:
                break;
            
            case ConsoleLoggerEventType.Clear:
                break;
            
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="ConsoleFlowDocument" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

My Problems are:

1. This Function is called from various worker thread so I must call the main thread via `ConsoleFlowDocument.Dispatcher.Invoke` which does block the thread (If I understand correctly) until the main thread executes the code block (not good performance especially with a lot of threads)
2. When I searched about ways to optimize the text viewing I came across this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8, which says : "***The FlowDocument element is a container for re-flowable documents that support rich presentation of content, and therefore, has a greater performance impact than using the TextBlock or Label controls.***", although the flowDocument was recommend multiple times on stackoverflow for similar task (Handling large amount of text)

   - [WPF: Best suited UI element to display a lot of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337357/wpf-best-suited-ui-element-to-display-a-lot-of-text/23338425)
     Which left me unsure about which control to use

Please Advice,
And thanks in advance

Comment: Use `BeginInvoke` to not block the thread - or push messages into a thread-safe buffer (producer-consumer pattern). For high-perf message display use a virtualised list control. Using FlowLayout is a very bad idea for this scenario.

Comment: Oh you are fast, thanks i did not know about `BeginInvoke`, but what is a "virtualised list control"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Dai So you suggest that I make a List of the logs and bind a `ListBox` to it, also I will be grateful if you make answer to show your point

Comment: Any reason why you not just append text to a `TextBlock`? It doesn't get more lightweight than this.